# Does ImageIO.getImageReaders() of Java work for SVG files?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert SVG to PNG and I should not use any third party dependencies. I have svg string and creating a svg file from it, now I would like to convert this file to png image. But I have an issue converting it. `imageReaderIterator.next()` has no next to return and throws exception. So, I thought `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` may not work for SVG files.

```
String inFilename = cgmPdfRequest.getModelName() + "_" + userId + ".svg";
String outFileName = cgmPdfRequest.getModelName() + "_" + userId + ".png";
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir() + "/" + inFilename)) {
    fileWriter.write(cgmPdfRequest.getSvgStr());
}
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir() + "/" + inFilename);
ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream);
Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaderIterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageInputStream);
ImageReader imageReader = imageReaderIterator.next();
BufferedImage img = imageReader.read(0);
File outFile = new File(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir() + "/" + outFileName);
ImageIO.write(img, "png", outFile);
```

Comment: ImageIO does not read SVG files.  Doing an internet search turns up several results, but they all use third-party libraries.

Comment: Yes I found multiple libraries, but I'm not supposed to use them.

Comment: It's SPI, so you can plug in whatever you want. Of the default implementations, no. It's all raster formats, no vectors: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/com/sun/imageio/plugins

Comment: Javafx handles svg, so if youre using an old oracle jdk8 then it doesn't need to be a "an external library"

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG), SVG is an XML-based vector image format.  Read the file, create a BufferedImage and save that as a PNG file.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Please explain how parsing an SVG XML file magically renders the intended graphical representation without implementing the SVG specification?

Comment: @ThomasBehr I'm not sure I get your point. You can create a javafx element that will render an svg image. https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/javafx-webview-overview

Comment: @matt Thank you very much for the link to the blog post.

Comment: Formats with built-in support in ImageIO: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html